# Include full directory structure, not individual files, in Go executable

Tags: go, tensorflow

I am trying to create an executable program with a trained tensorflow model. However, I have realised that the compiled Go script will need the model directory path as an argument. To avoid this I would like to include the model in the Go executable and compile them together. I have been looking at `go-bindata` but that doesn't work in this case because the function `tf.LoadSavedModel` takes a directory path to load the model, not the actual model files.

Do you know how this could be done?

EDIT:

`tf.LoadSavedModel` function (https://godoc.org/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/go#LoadSavedModel) needs the path of a directory to load a model. It is not able to process individual files, so thats why go-bindata (which is the solution of that question) doesn't work in this case. `tf.LoadSavedModel` uses a function in `C` to load files in a directory, so the files cannot be provided directly to Go. I hope that I explained it correctly

Comment: yeh, i cant see any way of doing that - the workaround would be to store in go-bindata and write them to a temp directory either as need or on app init, then load the models from there - you could also try serialising the SavedModel structs themselves and reconstructing but it depends whats done as part of the load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`golang.org/x/tools/godoc/vfs`](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/tools/godoc/vfs) or, say,
[`github.com/spf13/afero`](https://github.com/spf13/afero).

Combined with `go-bindata` or any other package providing
for embedding of file *contents,* it could be used to abstract away
filesystem-like trees (directory hierarchies).

---

Note that this approach presumes that "tensorflow" thing is able to
use such virtualization. If, instead, it insists on using a path
on a real filesystem, you'll need to work around this somehow.

One approach is to embed an archive file into your executable,
and then unpack it under a temporary directory during the program initialization phase.
Read up on [`io/ioutil.TempDir`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#TempDir).

Comment: You pointed me out in the right direction. I found this package that basically does what I want (https://github.com/glycerine/libzipfs).

Comment: Thanks for sharing!